# open print dialog that display only passed printer names or ip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I'm trying to print HTML page returned from ajax call using jQuery.print.js plugin and every things works fine expect i need to passed printer name or printer ip to function to display only passed printers for selection one to makes a print happen?

below I'll mention using code ...

this is my anchor tag that have on click function

```
    <a href="" data-order_no = "<?php echo $rest_order->id;?>" class="table-icon-saveprint icon" style="color: green;">print</a>
```

and this is my function that trigger preview and open print dialog

```
$(document).on( 'click', '[data-order_no] ', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
         var order_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-order_no');
         //Print ele4 with custom options
         $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Orders/print_order',
              data: {order_id: order_id}, //How can I preview this?
              dataType: 'html',
              success: function(result){
                  $("#test_prints").print({
                         //Use Global styles
                         globalStyles : false,
                         //Add link with attrbute media=print
                         mediaPrint : false,
                         //Custom stylesheet
                         stylesheet : "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata",
                         //Print in a hidden iframe
                         iframe : false,
                         //Don't print this
                          noPrintSelector : "#test_prints",
                         //Add this at top
                         //Add this on bottom
                         append : result, // result are html page i want to print
                         //Log to console when printing is done via a deffered callback
                         deferred: $.Deferred().done(function() { console.log('Printing done', arguments); })
                     });
              }
            });

         });
```

Now how I can display specific printers when print dialog are triggered using this way or another way are welcomed known I'm using php as backend language?

Any help please , And thanks in advance .

Best,

Answer (score 0):

> how I can display specific printers when print dialog are triggered?

Javascript in the browser does not have privileges or an API of any kind to access any of the information normally displayed in a print dialog.

So unfortunately this functionality is not currently possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response , I was wondering If there's any alternative solutions ?